# Drupal SMTP doesn't work for contact us page?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, smtp

I have installed a smtp module. and also test it with the test email id. it sends email to the test add.But doesn't work with the contact us page. it's not sending mail to admin. through the smtp or either php mail. as in drupal drupal_mail().

I just have configured smtp details in the admin section of the site.not anywhere else. though its working with test email so it should work with contact us page but it doesn't.

please help me.!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The email in the site information should be the same as the email in SMTP authentication** or
your mail goes nowhere!

Please check the [demo over here](http://iniu.net/content/install-tricky-drupal-smtp-module-email)...